# Autocomplete won't work for entity reference field unless User > Administer Users permission is granted

Tags: 8, entities, users, nodes, ajax

I have an entity reference field (users) on a node in D8, and the autocomplete suggestions won't show unless the **User > Administer Users** permission is granted to the role.

I'm trying to let event creators select who is presenting a certain topic, but I don't want them to be able to edit users' settings. Any ideas?

Comment: Aye - the alpha field permissions module seems to have been interfering somehow, thanks!

Comment: I moved it as answer if you'd like to let other know about the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint that provides AJAX entity reference completion (`system.entity_autocomplete` in **system.routing.yml**) is configured with with `requirements._access: 'TRUE'` property. This should make the **/entity_reference_autocomplete/%/%/%** path accessible to any user.

As such, check for any module that might be modifying its permissions.